# WPF - Como criar um mecanismo para disponibilizar a aplicação para teste durante x dias?

Tags: c#, wpf

bom dia

Estou criando uma aplicação em WCF e gostaria de ajuda ou direcionamento no seguinte ponto:
Preciso disponibilizar a aplicação para qualquer um baixar e testar a mesma, tipo um teste durante 30 dias e depois restringir o acesso.

Como posso criar um mecanismo destes em WPF ?

Agradeço desde já a atenção e ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que você precisaria do seguinte:

1. Salvar a data de instalação (Seja em um localDB ou no registro)
2. Identificar a data atual

Se você for fazer por data, você deverá se preocupar muito com relação a restrição, pois se o usuário mudar a data pode dar problema, e se você pegar a data de um WebService você obrigará que o usuário esteja conectado.

Fiz uma coisa semelhante um tempo atrás, porém não me preocupei muito em relação ao controle de data, fiz o seguinte:

O usuário poderá utilizar durante 30 dias ou X Utilizações (inicializações).

Ao iniciar o sistema, verifico se já passou a data, caso não tenha passado verifico se já passou as utilizações. Salvo as utilizações em um contador em um localDB junto com as informações do app.

Esta foi a melhor maneira, e a mais rápida que eu encontrei para fazer algo semelhante ao que você está querendo.